# Which Mathematica versions have changed WolframLibraryVersion?

Tags: librarylink

A LibraryLink library compiled with headers having a certain `WolframLibraryVersion` will not work with Mathematica versions that support only earlier `WolframLibraryVersion`s.

For example, a library compiled with M12.0 (`WolframLibraryVersion == 5`) will work not only in 12.0 but also in 12.1–13.0 (`WolframLibraryVersion == 6`). However, it will not work in 11.3 (`WolframLibraryVersion == 4`).

Which Mathematica versions use which `WolframLibraryVersion`?

Answer (score 24):

Run the following to find out the `WolframLibraryVersion` for your Mathematica, and please help complete the table below, if any entries are missing.

```
StringCases[
 Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "IncludeFiles", "C", "WolframLibrary.h"}], "String"],
 StartOfLine ~~ ___ ~~ "WolframLibraryVersion" ~~ 
   Whitespace .. ~~ (v : DigitCharacter ..) ~~ Whitespace ... ~~ 
   EndOfLine :> v
]
```

---

| Mathematica | WolframLibraryVersion |
| --- | --- |
| 13.1 – 14.0 | 7 |
| 12.1 – 13.0 | 6 |
| 12.0 | 5 |
| 11.2 – 11.3 | 4 |
| 10.0 – 11.1 | 3 |
| 9.0 | 2 |
| 8.0 | 1 |

---

##### Notes

- LibraryLink was not available before 8.0.

Comment: This table is now complete, but feel free to update once 13.1 comes out.

Answer (score 5):

When you come to version 13.1:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
dll = CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary["
#include <WolframLibrary.h>

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT mint get_WolframLibraryVersion() {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}
", "dllfile", "Language" -> "C++"];

dec=LibraryFunctionDeclaration[fun->"get_WolframLibraryVersion",dll,{}->"MachineInteger"];
WolframLibraryVersion = FunctionCompile[dec, Function[{}, fun[]]]
```

Then we can get the library version:

```
WolframLibraryVersion[]
```

> 7